# CAS with Django for Matrix SSO

Tags: django, single-sign-on, cas, matrix-synapse

I have a working Django (3.1) website and I'm trying to setup a Matrix Server (using Synapse) for the users.

How can I Setup Single Sign On for synapse (It supports SAML, CAS and OIDC) where only the users of my website could login to it?

I already implemented [Django CAS Server](https://github.com/nitmir/django-cas-server) and have a working login flow, but how can I send the token to Matrix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems no need to handle token at all!
Just set the cas base url as `cas_config: server_url` in `homeserver.yaml` of Matrix and it does the magic!